# Rename {language} to {languages}

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Per our tagging guidelines, tags should be plural if possible. So I think [language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) should be renamed to [languages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages).

(@Joseph: I think you misinterpreted my flag earlier.)

Similarly, [paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paragraph) should be [paragraphs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paragraphs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [languages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages) and [paragraphs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paragraphs) are done, keeping the singular just as synonym.