# Rename {dictionary} to {dictionaries}

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

... because we prefer plural tags. ([dictionary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) ⇒ [dictionaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionaries))

Similar questions:

- [Rename {language} to {languages}](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1135/4012)
- [Rename {script} to {scripts}](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2084/4012)
- [Pluralize these singular tags](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2086/4012)

And as we're talking about renaming tags already, I'd like to bring up my proposal to  **[Rename {mathmode} to {math-mode}](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2096/4012)** once again since it hardly gathered any reactions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now implemented :-) Not sure what else to say!

Comment: I guess that suffices, thanks :) (As for length requirements, an HTML comment is always something nice to say ... ;)